# How to send video converted to bitmap to Client using Indy TCPServer/Client?

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, delphi-7, indy

By the way, I'm sorry for my bad english.
I want to create a streaming video system between client and server using Indy with this scenario, Webcam with stepper motors connected directly to the server via the usb port. Then server do recording and images that have been captured send to client using socket, in this case i using Indy TCPSocket. This system is similar to the CCTV system. In other words, this system is one way communication. what i have done on coding is i convert the video into bitmap using this code :

```
procedure TFormHome.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VideoGrabber.GetBitmap(FormStream.Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
end;
```

but I am still confused how to transmit the images continuously to client so that the images that received by the client into a moving picture.because I know images can not be sent directly and must be converted to a byte array.

Maybe you can show me sample script to send a bitmap image to the client using Indy TCPServer / Client.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have the bitmap in a `TBitmap` object.  The simplest solution would be to save that to a `TStream` using `TBitmap.SaveToStream()`, then transmit it using Indy's `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` methods.

Comment: OK. I'll try it.. Thank's for your answer. ^^

Comment: @nurettin are you implementing an actual HTTP server? A web browser is not going to know how to display a JPEG as a JPEG if you just send it raw JPEG data without HTTP headers to describe the data as being a JPEG.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ooh I see, I didn't know they required http headers in the response for picture mime types (didn't think they were necessary for some reason). Cool, thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yep, that worked perfectly. Thanks for your time!